# Send mail to a particular user from subscriber list in Sendy API

Tags: email, sendy

I have multiple users in Subscriber list (suppose 10 users) and I want to send email to only one user from that list. I cannot create one list per user as I will need to generate report also. So how can I achieve this without making any changes in their core code.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this?